# VSCode Snippet Help/Chaining transform

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I thought I was getting the hang of making my own snippets, but I can't figure out to transform a tab stop so that 'Ignore/Before/Slashes/Oh Hey Text' becomes 'OhHeyText'.

so far I have this

```
${4/.*\\/(.+$)/$1/g}
```

or

```
${4/\\s//g}
```

But I can't figure out how to chain the transforms together. I've read through 5 or 6 posts here on SO already, but I'm having a lot of trouble grokking the actual transformation syntax, and extrapolating that to my use case.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: What is in your tabstop 4?  Text you enter, some filePath, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/^.*[\\/\\\\]|\\s+//g}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rw5y6c/2). *Details*:

- `^.*[\/\\]` - start of string, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then `/` or `\`
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

Comment: Man, you must dream in Regex, thanks a lot! I will add that this example actually did help me think about it in a new way (and wasn't just a copy/paste/forget answer)

Comment: @BenWong I forgot to add that `g` is important here, it makes the regex engine replace *all* found occurrences in the string. Otherwise, the alternation would not help.

Comment: If you don't mind, for the sake of my learning, how would you extend this regex alternating strategy to include a requirement that wasn't about deleting, like you had to keep the first letter after a slash and make it capitalized (as a silly example).

Comment: @BenWong If the task is to uppercase the first char after last `/`, you could use `"${TM_DIRECTORY/^.*(?=[\\/\\\\])|[\\/\\\\]([^\\/\\\\])(?=[^\\/\\\\]*$)|\\s+/${1:/upcase}/g}"`